# Can't drawImage a distant file on a local canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, cross-domain, drawimage

I have been reading how I need to set up CORS on my server and a crossdomain.xml to make the .drawImage() method work. I have been trying to implement all that, and I think I did it well.

Here is the HTTP header that comes with the image I'm trying to draw:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

And here is the crossdomain.xml: http://bew.ink/public/images/costum/crossdomain.xml

One of the pictures is located here: http://bew.ink/public/images/costum/non_printable_background.png

To me, everything seems correct, but when I try to draw this picture on a canvas, it just doesn't work:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

img.src = "http://bew.ink/public/images/costum/non_printable_background.png";
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: I am on a phone so quite hard to analyse clearly your image, but from the 300*150 px of the image you are drawing, it looks like they are all transparent. The only non transparent pixels of this image are way out of this top left corner. Maybe you wanted to draw it all? In this case add `canvas.width= this.width; canvas.height = thos.height;` before drawImage.

Comment: I feel stupid :D

Answer (score 0):

Okay this was such a stupid problem, thanks to @Kalido for giving the solution.

The images I am trying to draw have a wide transparent surface and are larger than my canvas, so all that's drawn is the transparent surface. That's why I don't see anything being drawn.